# Creating Time Intervals in R

Tags: r, data-science

I have a data set in R with 20,000 entries. Each entry has a specific time and date which it has occurred. I want to create time intervals of 6 hours each i.e - 6 AM-12 PM,12 PM - 6 PM... so on and so forth and ensure the data is sorted into that accordingly. The date is not needed I just need the data to be sorted according to the time interval.

For Example 
If an entry has the time of 12:35 PM it would be sorted into the 12 PM - 6 PM interval.

All ideas are welcome.
S.

Comment: So `12:35 PM` from two different dates ends up in the same bucket?  Can you share some sample data with us?

Comment: Yes , they would end up in the same bucket. Dates are not important.

Comment: I am sorry, I will not be able to share any data due to confidentiality reasons.

Comment: What format is your date column in?

Comment: Not a good way to get help here.  You can show us fake sample data, can't you?

Comment: Yes, ill get you fake data set.

Comment: the date column is as follows - year/month/day hours/minutes/seconds,

Comment: strptime() was used to convert the raw data into the above mentioned format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create a dataframe with a column that represents a time
df <- data.frame(MyTimes = c("02:50:00","06:00:00", "11:10:30", "13:15:50", "17:00:00", "23:45:20"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# create a "time interval" column
df$Interval <- NA
df$Interval[df$MyTimes %between% c("00:00:00", "06:00:00")] <- "0 AM - 6 AM"
df$Interval[df$MyTimes %between% c("06:00:00", "12:00:00")] <- "6 AM - 12 PM"
df$Interval[df$MyTimes %between% c("12:00:00", "18:00:00")] <- "12 PM - 6 PM"
df$Interval[df$MyTimes %between% c("18:00:00", "24:00:00")] <- "6 PM - 0 AM"
df
#    MyTimes     Interval
# 1 02:50:00  0 AM - 6 AM
# 2 06:00:00 6 AM - 12 PM
# 3 11:10:30 6 AM - 12 PM
# 4 13:15:50 12 PM - 6 PM
# 5 17:00:00 12 PM - 6 PM
# 6 23:45:20  6 PM - 0 AM
```

A **more efficient** way would be to convert first to seconds and then use 
*findInterval()*

```
   df$seconds <- period_to_seconds(hms(df$MyTimes))
    myIntervals <- c("0 AM - 6 AM", "6 AM - 12 PM", "12 PM - 6 PM", "6 PM - 0 AM")
    df$Interval<- myIntervals[findInterval(df$seconds, c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24) * 3600)]
    #    MyTimes     Interval seconds
    # 1 02:50:00  0 AM - 6 AM   10200
    # 2 06:00:00 6 AM - 12 PM   21600
    # 3 11:10:30 6 AM - 12 PM   40230
    # 4 13:15:50 12 PM - 6 PM   47750
    # 5 17:00:00 12 PM - 6 PM   61200
    # 6 23:45:20  6 PM - 0 AM   85520
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I shall try this on the data set and I will let you know the results.